# I need to merge a few html in google script code (goGet function)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-apps

Can somebody help me to solve this task?

I need to merge a few html in Google

```
script code. Example: function doGet() {
       return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
    }
```

I have a few HTML forms with different names like **index.html**, **x.html**, **box.html** and etc.

What is more, I have a ready Google script pattern and I want to launch a few forms, i.e I want to get a few links.

This is a clue thing. How can I get a few work links simultaneously? At this moment, I have only one link (one form) that hosts on Google script platform.

Comment: The following page might help: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Comment: Unfortunately, I had watched these help-pages an hour ago but I could not detect an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.  In Index.html place one of these where you want to include the other html files:

Option 1:

```
<!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import JavaScript. -->
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('jquery_cloneform_js').getContent(); ?>
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JavaScript').getContent(); ?>
```

Note that these are HTML files but the .html extension is not included even though it shows in the files list in the editor.

Option 2:
This goes in Index.html similar to above:

```
<!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import CSS. -->
<?!= include('GridView_Stylesheet'); ?>
```

with the going in a .js file:

```
function include(filename) {
//  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).evaluate()
      .getContent();
}
```

Either way, this method allows you to have html, css, scripts, etc which are loaded client side in different files and include them via the intial html file.